# Crawling an .net site with subdomain

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a .net site with php curl. The site that i am trying to crawl is

```
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com
```

i am able to crawl the site.

But when i am trying to crawl internal pages like

```
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com/about.asp
```

or any other page inside that sub-domain it gives me an error as follows

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.1
```

The code that i am using is as bellow

```
$ch = curl_init();
$urlLogin   =   "http://www.waltham.patriotproperties.com";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

The code works for

```
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com/
```

but does not work for

```
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com/search.asp
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com/summary.asp
```

ie any url within this sub domain.
 The error that i get with url inside the sub-domain is

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2013 16:33:57 GMT
Content-Length: 75
```

Comment: I do not think its the error with my code. I get an internal server error which is produced by the Microsoft server.I shall update my question with the error

Comment: i was able to get the page with command line curl (just "curl url", without cookies). I got a 200 OK ("curl -I url") for the "search.asp" file. it may be a problem with your cookies.txt file, try removing the file and retrying, or commenting the instructions related to the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting out at:

```
$urlLogin   =   "http://www.waltham.patriotproperties.com";
```

But the link for the search page is at:

```
http://waltham.patriotproperties.com/search.asp
```

If you surf to that URL, you'll see the content; if you add the `www.` to the start of the URL, it works.

**Editted to add** - this becomes a lot easier if they have an API you can use.

Comment: i have tried with and without "www". without www i get an 404 page not found error and with www i get an internal server error